# Regex capturing monetary expressions

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble using Regex in my simple python program. I'm trying to capture all monetary expressions of dollar amounts written out (eg: "five hundred dollars"," three hundred thousand dollars and forty cents"), but I'm having trouble.

My program just returns empty strings and while some initial feedback I received was that my regex is "too greedy" and overwriting, I'm unsure "how" and why it ultimately results in empty strings and how to fix it.

Here is my python code:

```
import re; 
import sys;
file2 = open("test2.txt", "r")
input_txt2 = file2.read() 
distjunct3 = r"(?:(?:(?:a|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve)?(?:(thir|four|fif|six|seven|eight|nine)teen)?)(?:(?:twen|thir|four|fif|six|seven|eight|nine)ty)?(?:(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten) (?:(?:hundred|thousand|)|(?:\w.llion)))?(?: \w+)? dollar(?:s)?(?: and [0-9]{1,2} cents)?)"
def repl(matchobj):
return "[" + matchobj.group() + "]";
print re.findall(distjunct3, input_txt2)
file2.close()
```

Here is my regex individually:

`(?:(?:(?:a|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve)?(?:(thir|four|fif|six|seven|eight|nine)teen)?)(?:(?:twen|thir|four|fif|six|seven|eight|nine)ty)?(?:(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten) (?:(?:hundred|thousand|)|(?:\w.llion)))?(?: \w+)? dollar(?:s)?(?: and [0-9]{1,2} cents)?)`

"I've tested my code on http://regexr.com/ and it seems to work with this sample text: exceed sixteen dollars y four dollars a head, but it is now reduced to one, and this charge they 
 valuable andto three thousand dollars: a los
hundred thousand dollars for twelve pounds for a dollar. Ths worth a dollar and n'tSix dollars--twelve skins, for a prime, dark
and tuck--eight or ten dollars, according to only two dollars.
"orth eight dollars; think of that!
one, worth twenty dollars--that's your value
dead, twenty dollars.
"Seven dollars the Factor pays in trade, which
eight-dollar coat."

I'm pretty stuck and would definitely appreciate any pointers, thanks!!

Comment: You only have non capturing groups, therefore they won't capture anything.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a good job for a regex.

Comment: Imo a better approach would be finding the word dollar(s) in the string, then going backwards until one of the words isn't in a list of number words.

Comment: @Natecat: how do you go backward with regex? Also I used non-capture groups for another example and it returned just fine.

Comment: Do you need to reject nonsense phrases like "one thirteen dollar"?

Comment: I think so - it would just be "thirteen dollars" ideally instead

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a simpler pattern. In pseudo regex, it's of the form: "`(number words)+ dollars (and (number words)+ cents)?`": (works for your input and more)

```
((?:(?:a|one|two|twen|thir|three|four|five|fif|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|hundred|thousand|million|billion)(?:y|ty|teen)?[\s-]?)+(?:[\s-]?dollars?(?: (?:and|&) (?:[0-9]{1,2}|no|(?:a|one|two|twen|thir|three|four|five|fif|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|hundred|thousand|million|billion)(?:y|ty|teen)?)+ cents)?))
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fA7kK1/2) output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
numwords = ["and", "a" ,"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",\
"nine", "ten", "eleven" "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen",\
"seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty",\
"seventy", "eighty", "ninety", "hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion"]
teststr = "exceed sixteen dollars y four dollars a head, but it is now reduced to one, and this charge they valuable andto three thousand dollars: a los hundred thousand dollars for twelve pounds for a dollar. Ths worth a dollar and n'tSix dollars--twelve skins, for a prime, dark and tuck--eight or ten dollars, according to only two dollars. \"orth eight dollars; think of that! one, worth twenty dollars--that's your value dead, twenty dollars"
splitstr = teststr.split()
dollarfound = []
for index, s in enumerate(splitstr):
    templist = []
    if s == "dollar" or s == "dollars":
        templist.append(splitstr[index])
        while (index-1 >= 0) and (splitstr[index-1] in numwords):
            templist.append(splitstr[index-1])
            index -=1
        dollarfound.append(" ".join(reversed(templist)))
print(dollarfound)
```

This code finds instances of the word dollar(s) and backtracks to get all number words before it. Your usecase doesn't really need regex.

Comment: Thank you!! But is there anyway to use regex? It's a required feature for my program :(
Edit: required in the  parameters of the assignment

Comment: What do you mean it's a required feature

Comment: Required in the assignment unfortunately!